# Не работает функция mail();

Tags: email, php

Всем привет. 
Я решил поставить себе регистрацию с подтверждением через почту. 
Сделал отправку сообщения через функцию `mail();`, вроде все нормально, сообщение отправляется, но есть одна очень большая проблема - не отображает текст сообщения. 
скрины:

1. http://prntscr.com/2fd019 - не открытое сообщение.
2. http://prntscr.com/2fd05v - открытое сообщение.

Пробывал регистрировать на несколько почт, все равно текста нет. 
Вот код, помогите пожалуйста:

```
<?php include ("bd.php");// файл bd.php должен быть в той же папке, что и все остальные, если это не так, то просто измените путь

// проверка на существование пользователя с таким же логином
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login'",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (!empty($myrow['id'])) {

exit ("Извините, введённый вами логин уже зарегистрирован. Введите другой логин."); //останавливаем выполнение сценариев

}

// если такого нет, то сохраняем данные
$result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO users (login,password,avatar,email,date) VALUES('$login','$password','$avatar','$email',NOW())");
// Проверяем, есть ли ошибки
if ($result2=='TRUE')
{

$result3 = mysql_query ("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login'",$db);//извлекаем идентификатор пользователя. Благодаря ему у нас и будет уникальный код активации, ведь двух одинаковых идентификаторов быть не может.
$myrow3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);
$activation = md5($myrow3['id']).md5($login);//код активации аккаунта. Зашифруем через функцию md5 идентификатор и логин. Такое сочетание пользователь вряд ли сможет подобрать вручную через адресную строку.

$subject = "Подтверждение регистрации";//тема сообщения
$message = "Здравствуйте! Спасибо за регистрацию на citename.ru\nВаш логин: ".$login."\n
Перейдите по ссылке, чтобы активировать ваш аккаунт:\nhttp://localhost/test3/activation.php?login=".$login."&code=".$activation."\nС уважением,\n
Администрация citename.ru";//содержание сообщение
mail($email, $subject, $message, "Content-type:text/plane; Charset=windows-1251\r\n");//отправляем сообщение

echo "Вам на E-mail выслано письмо с cсылкой, для подтверждения регистрации. Внимание! Ссылка действительна 1 час. <a href='index.php'>Главная страница</a>"; //говорим о отправленном письме пользователю
}

else {
exit ("Ошибка! Вы не зарегистрированы."); //останавливаем выполнение сценариев

     } ?>
```

Comment: Резко бросается в глаза, в код особо не вникал:  

    Content-type:text/plane

нужно  

    Content-Type:text/plain

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. Вот ведь грамотность как необходима :)

Comment:     localhost/test3/activation.php?login=0+UNION+SELECT+*+FROM+users

Comment: ну будем надеяться, что это именно тест, а не продакшн ;)